# Is it possible to use git bisect on git tags

Tags: git, bisect

I love using [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) especially for solving [regression bugs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FIPkJCmg55jR5zxK2XNBxQxtNSZWhFsSaD42ve0674A/edit#heading=h.km1taja0cie9). However, I realized that it can also be too granular: it points out the exact commit message, what if I simply would like to know in what release did a certain bug happen (by a release I mean a git tag)?

The above need not be mutually exclusive, I can start by finding out the tag that caused the bug, then simply rerun another git bisect on that tag as well.

Comment: Why not just convert the commit hash to its corresponding tag?

Comment: If Commit A causes the bug and it is fixed by Commit B, `git tag --contains A --no-contains B` prints the local tags that have the bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a total order over a set of tags, you can just `git bisect skip [range]` or `git bisect skip [range] [range] [range] ...` — where each `[range]` would be `tag1..tag2~1`, `tag2..tag3~1`, … — while in a `git bisect` session

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use git bisect on git tags

Yes, assuming you are using the correct tag name.
If not, git bisect will be clearer with Git 2.37:

"[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/945b9f2c31448d1c0d35cb4eedfc03e9d17d55c6/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> was too silent before it is ready to start computing the actual bisection, which has been corrected with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

See [commit f11046e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f11046e6def11a281a371918793226f30e3f8c12), [commit 0cf1def](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cf1defa5a6764b8a0fd956ff4d114cb014cb8a4) (11 May 2022) by [Chris Down (`cdown`)](https://github.com/cdown).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 945b9f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/945b9f2c31448d1c0d35cb4eedfc03e9d17d55c6), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cf1defa5a6764b8a0fd956ff4d114cb014cb8a4): output state before we are ready to compute bisection
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Chris Down</sup>

> Commit [73c6de0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c6de06aff8d14b5e9f55f393d25f1213f3d43d) (`bisect`: don't use invalid oid as rev when starting, 2020-09-25, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03a01824a4ee07cd06b152bbff45066d6cf5542b) listed in [batch #19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab4691b67bc1a2cd8d9068fb03e3fbd6979247d6)) ("bisect: don't use invalid oid as rev when starting") changes the behaviour of [`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cf1defa5a6764b8a0fd956ff4d114cb014cb8a4/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> to consider invalid oids as pathspecs again, as in the old shell implementation.
>
> While that behaviour may be desirable, it can also cause confusion.
> For example, while bisecting in a particular repo I encountered this:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect start d93ff48803f0 v6.3
> $
> ```
>
> ...which led to me sitting for a few moments, wondering why there's no printout stating the first rev to check.
>
> It turns out that the **tag was actually "6.3", not "v6.3"**, and thus the bisect was still silently started with only a bad rev, because `d93ff48803f0` was a valid oid and "`v6.3`" was silently considered to be a pathspec.
>
> While this behaviour may be desirable, it can be confusing, especially with different repo conventions either using or not using "`v`" before release names, or when a branch name or tag is simply misspelled on the command line.
>
> In order to avoid situations like this, make it more clear what we're waiting for:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect start d93ff4_8803f0 v6.3
> status: waiting for good commit(s), bad commit known
> ```
>
> We already have good output once the bisect process has begun in earnest, so we don't need to do anything more there.